# where should I extract android ndk to on a mac?

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk

Sorry if this sounds like a no-brainer. I would like to know if I have to extract the Android NDK to any particular folder on my Mac or if can be extracted any where?

Comment: Put it anywhere you like. Personally, I put all the ndk and sdk things in `/Users/Shared/Android`, so other users could access them too, if needed. You just have to set the location in your IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be extracted anywhere. Almost anywhere. Avoid paths with spaces, e.g. `/Users/N Sologistic`.

Answer (score 0):

to ~/

~/ is your home directory i.e. /Users/yourShortName/

Thats automatically searches for libraries.